# React native iap can't fetch products (subscriptions) from Apple account

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, react-native-iap

Stuck with implementing react native iap. connection success. But subscription plans goes error.

Installed package

```
npm i react-native-iap
```

Sourcecode

```
import * as RNIap from 'react-native-iap'
```

Connection seems successful:

```
RNIap.initConnection() //return true
```

not getting subscription plans

```
RNIap.getAvailablePurchases(['PCKGIDS']) //no response
```

Instead a pop up alert box appears, prompting to sign in to the Apple account, failing to sing in to that and showing as incorrect password